# single layer perceptron convergence

Tags: r, machine-learning, perceptron

I'm trying to classify iris data whether the flower is a setosa or not using perceptron but it doesn't converge correctly.

```
pla=function(x,y,w=NULL){

  n=ncol(x)
  w=as.vector(length(n))
  t=0
  iter=0
  e=los(x,y,w)

  while(e != 0 && iter<=100){
 print(paste("iteration: ",iter,"__________________________________________"))

    for (i in 1:nrow(x )){
      if (sign(t(w)%*%x[i,])!=y[i]){
        w=w+y[i]%*%x[i,]
        t=t+1
        print(paste( "Update: ", t, " | Weights (w): ", w[1], w[2], w[3], "Ls(w) : ", e))
        }
    }
    e=los(x,y,w)
    iter=iter+1
   abline(-w[1]/w[3],w[2]/w[3],col="green")

  }

  print(paste( "end with iter=",iter," Update: ", t, " | Weights (w): ", w[1], w[2], w[3], "Ls(w) : ", e))

  abline(-w[1]/w[3],w[2]/w[3],col="red")
  return(w)
}
```

At the begining the lost was 1 but after that it's always 0.3333333333. and I get 50 or more warnings:

```
In if (sign(t(w) %*% x[i, ]) != y[i]) { ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Something is going bad with my if but I can't figure it out. Thanx for helping me it's a homework and I'm not familiar with R

Comment: maybe u can add `print(sign(t(w) %*% x[i, ]))` before the if statement

Comment: @chinsoon12 i did it now its a matrix and it should be a vector since i'm multiplying w witch is a vector by x witch is a matrix. any idea how to solve this?

Comment: we can tell you but it will not be helping you

Comment: @chinsoon12 ok but i tried to use xk=as.vector(sign(t(w) %*% x[i, ]) but it doesnt' work neither i'm i on the right way or not. w is a 1*3 vector and x is a 150*3

Comment: the warning is tell you that you are comparing a vector with a single value while expecting a single boolean

Comment: @chinsoon12 sorry but when i print sign(t(w) %*%x[i,]) it was a matrix not a vector and i think it chould be a vector of nrow(x) having-1 o 1 as values. Then i can compare it element by element with y. I will try to correct what u told me and see. Thnak you